# How to match Regex right to left in php

Tags: php, regex

This my simple data : `<table></table><table></table><table>aaa</table>`

how to replace `<table></table><table></table>***<table>aaa</table>***`

it should be return `<table></table><table></table>`

Comment: Clarify question. It doesn't make too much sense right now. Use more words, less asterisks.

Comment: You could get all matches with `preg_match_all` and just take the last one.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the last `<table>` element, then you can perhaps use this pattern:

```
.*(<table>.*</table>)
```

This will capture the last `<table>.*</table>` into group 1 ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/FXfkkmjrC8)).

That said, you probably shouldn't use regex to parse HTML. If at all possibly, use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
$txt = '<table></table><table></table><table>aaa</table>';
print preg_replace('@(.*)(<table>aaa</table>)$@','\\1***\\2***',$txt);
```